# Conformal map from $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|>1\}\setminus (-\infty,-1)$ onto $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$

Tags: complex-analysis, alternative-proof, solution-verification, conformal-geometry

Find a conformal map from the set 
$\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|>1\}\setminus (-\infty,-1)$ onto the set $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$.

Here is my thought, but I'm not sure if it is correct, can anyone help me to verify my answer?

1: $\frac{1}{z}$ maps the set to $\mathbb{D}\setminus(-1,0]$.

2: $z^{1/2}$ maps the disk with slit to the right half disk.

3: rotate the right half disk to lower half disk.

4: the map $z+1/z$ maps the lower half disk to upper half plane.

5: rotate the upper half plane to right half plane.

6: $z^2$ maps the right half plane to $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$.

Also, if anyone can think of an alternate route, it would be nice to see! Thanks!

Comment: you have to keep track of the part that is cut out:(1) $\setminus (-1,0)$ ,(2) $\setminus (0,i)$, (3) $\setminus (0,1)$, (4) $(2,+\infty)$, (5) $(-2i, -i\infty)$, (6) $(-4,-\infty)$ (7) just add $4$ then you get: $(0,-\infty)$ although this is not the desired form, zero should be included.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks right to me.

I did this first: $z\to \sqrt z \to 1/\sqrt z.$ That leaves us in the right half disc. I'd prefer the upper half disc, so multiply by $i.$ Then we apply the map $(1+z)/(1-z),$ which takes us to the first quadrant. Rotate clockwise by $\pi/4,$ i.e., multiply by $e^{-i\pi /4}.$ Finally the map $z^4$ puts us in the desired domain. The formula I got is

$$z \to -\left(\frac{1+i/\sqrt z}{1-i/\sqrt z}\right)^4.$$

I think we are doing basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that worked for me was to use the open 1st quadrant $Q_\mathrm{I} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < \mathrm{arg}(z) < \frac{\pi}{2} \}$ as an intermediate domain.

You can produce a conformal bijection $f : Q_\mathrm{I} \to \mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$ as follows.

> - $z^4$ maps $Q_\mathrm{I}$ to $\mathbb{C} \setminus [0,\infty)$.
> - $-z$ maps $\mathbb{C} \setminus [0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$.

You can produce a conformal bijection $g: Q_\mathrm{I}  \to \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|>1\}\setminus (-\infty,-1)$ as follows.

> - The Cayley transform $\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ maps the upper half plane to the unit disk and, restricting, maps $Q_\mathrm{I}$ to the lower half disk.
> - $z^2$ maps the lower half disk to the disk minus $[0,1)$.
> - $\frac{1}{z}$ maps the disk  minus $[0,1)$ to $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|>1\}\setminus (1,\infty)$.
> - $-z$ maps $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|>1\}\setminus (1,\infty)$ to $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|>1\}\setminus (-\infty, -1)$.

Then you can use $g \circ f^{-1}$ to get a conformal bijection between the desired domains.

By the way, your approach seems good, although I didn't check that $z + \frac{1}{z}$ does what you claim.